# Aborted (core dumped) in solana-test-validator

Tags: testing, anchor, solana

I tried solana-test-validator.
I have got the following error message.

```
“Aborted (core dumped)”
```

How can I solve it?

- os : ubuntu 20.0.4 (vmware)
- solana version : solana-cli 1.9.4
- cluster : localhost

Comment: You could add some more context to your question like what OS? What version of Solana (`solana --version`)? What cluster are you configured for (`solana config get`)?

Answer (score 2):

https://forums.solana.com/t/solana-test-validator-error-missing-avx2/3272

Try to run `solana-test-validator --log` to see this kind of output. Your error probably rely on CPU AVX2 instructions that yours doesn't have.

Comment: Build Solana from source and run `./solana/validator/solana-test-validator` then it should work https://github.com/solana-labs/solana

Comment: Then you can add this function to your ~/.bashrc so it hits this version everytime
`solana-test-validator () {
   ~/sol-workspace/solana/validator/solana-test-validator
}
`